# must read c++ publications

Tags: c++

1. What are the prominent c++ online publications that an aspiring c++ must read? The Wall Street Journal projection from the financial world to the c++ world? I am less interested in blogs, but more solid, heavyweight, reviewed publications.
2. It looks to me that boost and templates are the new black, and there are books of course, however I don't see that many articles going on (see #1 above, maybe that's the reason).
3. What are the prominent c++ mailing lists that the serious c++ programmer must subscribe to.

Comment: Please re-read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Not online, but though I'd mention it anyway: You're probably familiar with [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely a must read, **[GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/)**
This is a wrong place to ask this question though.

Comment: And this is a wrong place to write a ***comment*** :)

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: Well, it answers the Question, doesn't it? You can't but deny that GotW is a not an answer to the Q.

Comment: :) It does, it does... The question is: is an answer to not a real question an answer? :))) Just kidding, here's a +1 from me :)

Comment: Why would it be the wrong place to ask? Because the #1 roll that every c++ dev must read is stackoverflow?

Comment: @MockInterface: Did you read the faq link provided by @Mat? in comments, that answers your question.